# How to display 2 contents side by side on full page - Bootstrap / CSS/ laravel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have 2 contents which I trying to display side by side on full page and One under the other when its small size screen(mobile) . I kinda succeed to display them  side by side on full page but when its small screen size they are on top of each other .

This is my master.blade page where I am including both of them with

```
@yield:

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 20px; ">MyHero &copy; {{ date('Y') }} </p>
      </div>
      @yield('map') // content 1
      @yield('Contact') // content 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>

</footer>
```

My css for section ('map') 
  @section ('map')

```
<div class="map" style="height:300px;width: 500px;display: block; float: left;">
```

My css for section ('contact')

@section('Contact')

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <div class="cont" style="height:300px;width: 500px; display: block; float: right;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

Essentially, all I have done wrap your 2 2 `@yield()` in a bootstrap's grid class, this will be 2 columns on the page, and on medium devices and below should drop below one another.

[Bootstrap 3.3 Grid System Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

```
<footer>  
    <div class="container">  
        <hr>
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-12" > 
                <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 20px; " >MyHero &copy; {{ date('Y') }} </p>
            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-6">
                    @yield('map') / content 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    @yield('Contact') / content 2
            </div>

        </div> 
    </div> 
    <br><br><br>

</footer>
```

Comment: Nope :( Didn't help . Same issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try using flexbox. The divs adjust according to available viewport width. Note that it is always good practice to define your styles separately instead of inline.

```css
.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.map, .cont {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height:300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">  
        <hr>
        <div class="col-md-12" > 
                <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 20px; " >MyHero &copy; {{ date('Y') }} </p>
            </div> 
        <div class="row"> 
            


                    <div class="map">content 1
                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="cont">
                    content 2
                    </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: It did not help.Your solution just displaying them one under the other at any screen size .  I need them to be one under the other only when its small screen size.

Comment: If you open the code snippet, go to full screen and resize the screen you will see it does just what you want.

Comment: It does work if I only write a simple string , but when I do @yield it's displays the content one on top of the other